# Android Studio Git push fatal Error 403

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github, git-push

Hi i have clone a repository in android studio 1.4.1 , but when i am trying to push some commits i receive this screen [android studio error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSHJP.jpg).
My `.git` directory config settings is here [git config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMhoU.jpg).
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

It is an authorization issue.

Using the https protocol you can pull from https without password if you clone a repo, but you can't push to a https repo without password.

Otherwise, configure your public ssh key into your github account and use the git protocol instead of https.